# How do I use SQL to create a virtual column that sums the number of seats per row?

Tags: sql, oracle

**CANNOT ADD VIRTUAL COLUMN WITH THE PROPER CONDITIONS**

Using sql, I was tasked to create a database representing an ER diagram. I have two tables that I believe are specific to the question I have to ask:

- table 1: "seat" and
- table 2:"row"

I wish to write SQL for the question
which is:

> Add a virtual column to calculate the total number of seats in each row.

The creation of the tables in question is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "row"(
"rowID" NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
numbers NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
seats NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
auditoriumID NUMBER(5),
CONSTRAINT row_aud_fk FOREIGN KEY(auditoriumID) REFERENCES auditorium(auditoriumID));

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_row
START WITH 10
INCREMENT BY 1
MAXVALUE 100
NOCYCLE
CACHE 5;

CREATE TABLE seat(
seatID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
"rowID" NUMBER(5),
numbers NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
"name" NVARCHAR2(26) NOT NULL,
typeID NUMBER(5),
CONSTRAINT seat_row_fk FOREIGN KEY("rowID") REFERENCES "row"("rowID"),
CONSTRAINT seatType_fk FOREIGN KEY(typeID) REFERENCES "seatType"("typeID"));

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_singularseat
START WITH 1000
INCREMENT BY 1
MAXVALUE 10000
NOCYCLE
CACHE 5;
```

The major road blocks are that I have to use an arithmetic expression and cannot use a sub-query (or at least it did not work for me)

PS: since there is no restriction to which table this should have, you may try row as well. Seat seemed as a more likely choice for me.

An example of what I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE seat
ADD total_seats_per_row NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM seat s WHERE s.rowID = seat.rowID) VIRTUAL;
```

Comment: seems like you're supposed to write DML and not DDL, please add any DML that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your example (no foreign keys, removed double quotes (I just *hate* them).

```
SQL> create table seat
  2    (seat_id     number primary key,
  3     row_id      number,
  4     seat_number number
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create table t_row
  2    (row_id     number primary key,
  3     row_number number
  4    );

Table created.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> insert all
  2    into t_row values (1, 1)
  3    into t_row values (2, 2)
  4    into seat  values (1, 1, 3)         --> 4 seats in row 1
  5    into seat  values (2, 1, 4)
  6    into seat  values (3, 1, 8)
  7    into seat  values (4, 1, 11)
  8    into seat  values (5, 2, 6)         --> 1 seat in row 2
  9  select * From dual;

7 rows created.
```

Due to certain restrictions on virtual columns (can't reference columns from other tables), I'll create a **deterministic** function (must be; otherwise, that won't work):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_total_seats_per_row (par_row_id in number)
  2    return number deterministic
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select count(*) into retval
  7      from seat
  8      where row_id = par_row_id;
  9    return retval;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Virtual column:

```
SQL> alter table t_row add
  2    (total_seats_per_row as (f_total_seats_per_row(row_id)));

Table altered.
```

Testing:

This is what an ordinary query returns:

```
SQL> select row_id, count(*) number_of_seats from seat group by row_id;

    ROW_ID NUMBER_OF_SEATS
---------- ---------------
         1               4
         2               1
```

What does table that contains virtual column return? The same data:

```
SQL> select * from t_row;

    ROW_ID ROW_NUMBER TOTAL_SEATS_PER_ROW
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1          1                   4
         2          2                   1
```

What if we add another seat into the 2nd row?

```
SQL> insert into seat values (6, 2, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t_row;

    ROW_ID ROW_NUMBER TOTAL_SEATS_PER_ROW
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1          1                   4
         2          2                   2
                                        ^ 
                                        |
                     here it is; 2 seats in the 2nd row
```

See if it helps.

Comment: `f_total_seats_per_row` is **NOT** deteministic. You may have declared it to be deterministic to force the compiler to accept the code but that does not mean that the function is or that the code will work as expected (as the value is likely to be cached and then once the value in the table changes the cache will be out-of-date and the function will return the wrong values).

Comment: I am new to this deterministic function concept, could someone clarify , how does the function or where from is the function getting the input to derive the values

Comment: Deterministic functions return the same result for the same input. Google for more info. As of this very problem, this is a way to do that. I presume you'd rather create a **view** (as a join of these two tables) that returns desired result (number of seats per row). But, if it must be a virtual column and you don't have any other option, then this (my example) is how it goes.

Comment: @MTO is correct, I believe.  From the Oracle docs: _"Do not specify DETERMINISTIC for a function whose result depends on the state of session variables **or schema objects**, because results might vary across invocations."_